# Query to find latest Date of the DateColumn which inserted into table?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table called `tbl_EmployeeSalaryHistory` which contains following values:

```
History_Id   Salary_Date  Employee_Id
____________________________________

1001          2015-08-02   10
1002          2015-09-03   10
1003          2015-10/02   10
1004          2015-08-01   11
1005          2015-09-05   12
```

I want to know **last salary date** for `Employee_Id = 10`.

Anyone knows how to write a query for that?

Comment: Salary_Date is auto generated or you enter manually???

Comment: Salary_Date is manually enter into table.. Other people suggest me to use MAX(Salary_Date).

Comment: if you want to get last salary date of specific id then MAX(Salary_Date) is good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Use [sql Max function](http://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/max-date.php) for latest date in the table.

```
select MAX(Salary_Date) from tbl_EmployeeSalaryHistory where Employee_Id=10
```

hope this helps.

Comment: what is the datatype of column `salary_date`.if its i `varchar`,change it to `date` type. and make sue you have an entry for `employee_id` 10.

Comment: then u should get value for above query if there is entry for `employee id ` 10

Comment: @Parameswaran, you need to accept this answer if it is working fine :)